# SAS Array Calculations Row Operations

Tags: arrays, sas

I have a dataset that has a list of contributions of members of a sales organization by day.  What I want to ultimately end up with is the following information:

For each day:

- How much the entire team sold. ($200 for day one, $350 for day two..)
- How much a designated subset ("Joe"...for example) of that team sold (Joe sold $100 day one, $200 day two...)
- the difference in the above two calculations ($200-$100 for day one, $350-$200 for day two....)
- how many total people contributed that day (2 in day 1, 3 in day two, 5 in day 3)
- how many of my designated subset contributed that day (1 every day in this case, since Joe was there every day)

In the example below, Joe is my designated subset.  The problem I am having is directing SAS to only sum up Joe's contributions.  The method I have below works, but only if Joe is the only contributor AND if he contributes every day.  I basically force him to be the first entry, then point to him.  This fails if he is not there one day, or if my subset has multiple people.

Below is my attempt I've been working on, but I think I'm going down the wrong path, since this will not be dynamic enough when I add more people.  For example, if the subset now becomes Joe and Sue....the calculation will still just point to Joe.  If I point it two first two obs, it may select hal accidentally from day one.  Is there a way to specify by rom "Only add the Amount column if the name next to it is either Joe or Sue? Help!

```
*declare team;
/*%let team=('joe','sue');*/
%let team=('joe');

*input data;
data have;
    input day name $ amount;
cards;
1 hal 100
1 joe 100
2 joe 80
2 sue 70
2 jim 200
3 joe 50
3 sue 100
3 ted 200
3 tim 100
3 wen 5000
;
run;

*getting my team to float to top of order list;
data have;
    set have;
    if name in &team. then order=1;
    else order=2;
run;

*order;
proc sort data=have;
    by day order name;
run;

*add running count by day;
data have;
    set have;
    by day;
    x+1;
    if first.day then x=1;
run;

*get number of people on team;
proc sql noprint;
    select count(distinct name) into :count
    from have 
    where name in &team.;
quit;

*get max of people per day;
proc sql noprint;
    select max(x) into :max_freq from have;
quit;

*pre transpose...set labels;
data have;
    set have;
    varname=cats('Name_',x);
    value=name;
    output;
    varname=cats('Amount_',x);
    value=amount;
    output;
    keep day value varname;
run;

*transpose;
proc transpose data=have out=have_transp(drop=_NAME_);
    by day;
    id varname;
    var value;
run;


data want;
    set have_transp;
    array Amount {*} Amount:;
    TOT_Amount=0;
    NUM_TOTAL_PEOPLE=0;
    do i=1 to dim(Amount);
        if Amount[i]>0
        then 
            do;
                TOT_Amount+Amount[i];
                NUM_TOTAL_PEOPLE+1;
            end;
    end;
    TEAM_CONTRIB=Amount_1;
    NON_TEAM_CONTRIB=TOT_Amount-TEAM_CONTRIB;

run;
```

A few other things:

- Every member of the team will not always be present every day
- There are very many possibilities for how many people might be on the total team and/or subset

Comment: Do you have to use arrays, is this a solution you're interested in pursuing? I think proc means can be used more efficiently...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using proc means that doesn't use arrays. Proc means will calculate data at different levels by default when using the CLASS and TYPES statements. The data can then be merged into the appropriate level. In this solution it doesn't matter how many people are in the group/subset or that everyone is present for every day.

```
/*Subset group*/
data subteam;
input name $;
cards;
joe
sue
;
run;

/*Sample data*/
data have;
    input day name $ amount;
cards;
1 hal 100
1 joe 100
2 joe 80
2 sue 70
2 jim 200
3 joe 50
3 sue 100
3 ted 200
3 tim 100
3 wen 5000
;
run;

*Set group variable for subset team;
data have;
set have;
group=0;
run;

*Set group variable=1 to subset;
proc sql;
update have
set group=1 
where name in (select name from subteam);
quit;

*Calculate sums;
proc means data=have;
class day group;
types day day*group;
var amount;
output out=want1 sum=total n=count;
run;

*Reformat into desired format;
data want2;
merge want1 (where=(group=.) rename=(total=total_overall count=count_overall))
      want1 (where=(group=1) rename=(total=total_group count=count_group));
by day;

run;
```

Comment: I didn't even think to use proc means in this way.  This works for what I need.  Thank you!